# Get results from 2d array using other array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 5
)
```

and other one

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [v1] => aa
            [v2] => ss
        )
.
.
.
.

    [4] => Array
        (
            [v1] => vv
            [v2] => dd
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [v1] => gg
            [v2] => rr
        )
)
```

The question, how can I get results from the second array using values in the first one.
The output should be looking like this

```
[4] => Array
    (
        [v1] => vv
        [v2] => dd
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [v1] => gg
        [v2] => rr
    )
```

I'm trying some function like array_intersect and array_values but It didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_intersect_key` and `array_flip`:

```
$result = array_intersect_key($secondArray, array_flip($firstArray));
```

Comment: Ha. Didn't see your answer before I posted my (identical) answer. Great minds eh? ;)

Comment: :) no problem.. there are a lot of answers using the foreach loop but we thought it will be nicer to use these built in functions :)

Answer (score 1):

This would iterate trough the first array and get the values from the second array.

```
$newarray=array();
foreach ($array1 as $v) {
    $newarray[$v] = $array2[$v];
}
```

Comment: No problem, don't forget to pick an accepted answer then ;)    Also thank you @Sougata for the answer improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You may do it like this:

```
$output = array();

foreach( $first_array as $v ){
    $output[$v] = $second_array[$v];
}

//$output has
//[4] => Array
//(
//    [v1] => vv
//    [v2] => dd
//)

//[5] => Array
//(
//    [v1] => gg
//    [v2] => rr
//)
```

Comment: Thank you . . 
I have more than one key, is it work ?

Answer (score 0):

try doing something like this

```
$array_a;/* 
    Array
    (
        [0] => 4
        [1] => 5
    )*/
    $result = array() ;
    foreach ($array_a as $res){
        if ( array_key_exists($array_b[$res])  ){
            $result[] = $array_b[$res] 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the executed code.

```
<?php

 $array1 = array(3,5);

 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($array1);

 $array2 = array();
 $array2[0] = array('v1'=>'aa','v2'=>'ss');
 $array2[3] = array('v1'=>'vv','v2'=>'dd');
 $array2[4] = array('v1'=>'xx','v2'=>'yy');
 $array2[5] = array('v1'=>'gg','v2'=>'rr');
 print_r($array2);

 $array3 = array();
 for($i=0;$i<=count($array1)-1;$i++)
 {
    if (array_key_exists($array1[$i], $array2))
          $array3[$array1[$i]] = $array2[$array1[$i]];
 }  

 print_r($array3);

 ?>
```

Comment: Well that's one old way of doing it.

Comment: may be but it results the same which is requested. :)

Comment: Yeah, it's a valid solution but it costs more coding than a simple foreach